# How to use sprintf in Perl to get a float variable upto 2 decimal places without being rounded off

Tags: perl

Consider:

```
my $var = 37.43745;
my $res = sprintf("%.2f",$var);
print $res;
```

The above code will give the output as 37.44. But I want output to be 37.43 only. How can I get it using sprintf in a Perl script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my $var = 37.43745;

my $res = sprintf("%.2f", int($var * 100) / 100);

print $res;
```

Comment: This will render two decimal places if the second decimal place is zero.

Comment: this will return 37.29 if input is 37.30.

Answer (score 0):

```
$var= int($var*100)/100;
```

This will be easiest solution I guess.

Comment: This will render one decimal place if the second decimal place is zero.

Comment: @hochgurgler agree, but OP was not specific about that